# Designing a database to save and query a dynamic range?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, range

I need to design a (postgres) database table which can save a dynamic range of something.

Example:
We have a course table. Each course can have (a minimum AND a maximum) OR (a specific amount) of participants.
A math course can be started with 4 to 10 students while a physics course needs to have exactly 8 students to start.

After that, I want to be able to query that.
Let's say, I want all courses which can take 6 students. The math course should be returned, the physics course shouldn't as it requires exactly 8 students.

When I query for 8 students, both courses should be returned.

---

For the implementation I thought about two simple fields: `min_students` and `max_students`. Then I could simply check if the number is equal to or between these numbers.

The issue is: I have to fill both columns everytime. Also for the physics course which requires exactly 8 students.

example:

```
name    | min_students | max_students 
--------|--------------|-------------
math    |            4 |           10
physics |            8 |            8
```

Is there a more elegant/efficient way? I also thought about making the max_students column nullable so I could check for 
`min_students = X OR (min_students >= X AND max_students <= Y)`

Would that be more efficient? What about the performance?

Answer (score 2):

> Each course can have (a minimum AND a maximum) OR (a specific amount) of participants.

All courses has a minimum and a maximum, for some courses it happens to be the same value. It might seem trivial but thinking about it that way lets you define the problem in a simpler way.

Instead of:

```
min_students == X OR (min_students >= X AND max_students <= Y)
```

you can express it as:

```
num_students BETWEEN min_students AND max_students
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, so `8 BETWEEN 8 and 8` is true

### Regarding optimizations

Additional conditionals makes queries exponentially harder to understand for humans and that leads to missed edge cases and usually results in inefficient queries anyway. Focus on making the code easy to understand, or "elegant", and never sacrifice readability for performance unless you are *really* sure that you have a performance issue in the first place and that your optimization actually helps.

If you have a table with 10M rows it might be worth looking at super optimizing disk usage if you run on extremely limited hw but reducing the disk usage of a table even with 20 MB is almost certainly wasting time in any normal circumstance even when it doesn't make the code more complicated.

Besides, each row takes up 23-24 bytes in addition to any actual data it contains so shaving of a byte or two wouldn't make a big difference. Setting values to NULL can actually *increase* disk usage in some situations.

### Alternative solution

When using a range data type the comparison would look like this:

```
num_students @> x
```

where `num_students` represents a range (for example 4 to 10) and `@>` means "contains the value"

```
create table num_sequence (num int);
create table courses_range (name text, num_students int4range);

insert into num_sequence select generate_series(3,10);
insert into courses_range values 
  ('math', '[4,4]'), ('physics', '[6,7]'), ('dance', '[7,9]');

select * from num_sequence 
left join courses_range on num_students @> num;


 num |  name   | num_students 
-----+---------+--------------
   3 |         | 
   4 | math    | [4,5)
   5 |         | 
   6 | physics | [6,8)
   7 | physics | [6,8)
   7 | dance   | [7,10)
   8 | dance   | [7,10)
   9 | dance   | [7,10)
  10 |         |
```

Note that the ranges are output formatted like [x,y), hard brackets means inclusive while parenthesis means exclusive and that for integers: [4,4] = [4,5) = (3,5)